# Upper/lower bounds for an unusual function

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

How can I obtain some good upper/lower bounds on the function

$$ f(k)= \frac{-p}{\log_2{\left( 1-2^{-k} \right)}}$$

for $0<k<p$? I have an algorithm where the runtime comes down to this expression, and I have no idea how to figure out how it will grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0 < x < 1$ we have

$$x < -\ln(1-x) = \int_{1-x}^1 \frac{dt}{t} < \frac{x}{1-x},$$

and

$$-\log_2(1 - 2^{-k}) = \frac{-\ln(1 - 2^{-k})}{\ln 2}.$$

Hence,

$$\frac{1}{(\ln 2) \,2^k}= \frac{2^{-k}}{\ln 2}<-\log_2 (1 - 2^{-k}) < \frac{ 2^{-k}}{\ln 2 (1 - 2^{-k})} = \frac{1}{\ln 2(2^k - 1)},  $$

and

$$p(\ln 2)(2^k-1)<\frac{-p}{\log_2 (1 - 2^{-k})}<p(\ln 2) 2^k$$